# Can a closed surface of genus $\geq$ 2 be embedded in a product of graphs?

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $S$ be a closed orientable surface of genus $g \geq 2$.  Is there an embedding of $S$ into the product of two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$?  I can't think of such an embedding but I don't know any obstructions for this sort of thing.

Comment: I am pretty sure I can prove that the image of $S$ in $G_1 \times G_2$ is a simplicial subcomplex (of the same dimension), but I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: Maybe it is not impossible. Here is an idea that I do not have the visual intuition to make work: Maybe you can embed the pair of pants in some product of graphs; this just amounts to embedding a cylinder, and then ignoring a simplex on the interior. Once you've done this, you'd like to repeatedly enlarge the graph so that you can embed copies of these next to each other, glued along the boundary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A genus $g$ surface can be found in the product $G_{g+1} \times G_{g+1}$ where $G_n$ is the 2 vertex graph with $n$ edges in between them. To do this for the genus two case, if $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are the edges, you can remove from $G_3 \times G_3$ the three faces $e_i \times e_i$.  You can check that it is a closed surface since every edge is on two faces, and then you can compute the Euler characteristic to see it is genus 2.

Higher genus is similar.  As mentioned before, these will never be objective on the level of fundamental groups.

Comment: Nice! I like this a lot.